# Get radio button value of child element jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, laravel

I'm trying to make an AJAX search call with Select2. The input data depends on the selected radio button which is displayed above the select field.

Whenever I click the selectbox, the selected value of the radio buttons above it should be read and change the `choice` variable. However, when I click the selectbox, it changes the `choice` variable only once. If I click again, it doesn't change anymore. Why does this happen and how can I fix it? Thanks!

```
<div class="group">
    <label class="mdl-radio mdl-js-radio mdl-js-ripple-effect" for="partner">
        {{Form::radio('partnersupplier', 'partner', true, array('class' => 'mdl-radio__button partnersupplier', 'id' => 'partner'))}}
        <span class="mdl-radio__label">Partner </span>
    </label>
    <label class="mdl-radio mdl-js-radio mdl-js-ripple-effect margin-radio" for="supplier">
        {{Form::radio('partnersupplier', 'supplier', false, array('class' => 'mdl-radio__button partnersupplier', 'id' => 'supplier'))}}
        <span class="mdl-radio__label">Leverancier </span>
    </label>
    <div class="form-group" >
        <label for="x">label<br></label>

        <select id="x" name="x" class="searchselect searchselectstyle partnersupplierselect">
        </select>

    </div>
</div>
```

Here's my JS

```
var choice = 'partner';

    $('.partnersupplierselect').on('click', function(){
        var group = $(this).parent().parent();
        choice = group.find('.partnersupplier:radio:checked').val();
        console.log(choice);

        group.find('.partnersupplierselect').select2({
            ajax: {
                dataType: "json",
                type: "POST",
                data: function (params) {
                    return {
                        term: params.term,
                        '_token': token,
                        'choice': choice
                    };

                  // the rest is just the Select2 initialization
                  // console.log only gives once the value when I click it, and then never again
```

Here's the selectbox after it's being clicked:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="yearlypartnersuppliermaintainance">Kies partner / leverancier jaarlijks onderhoud<br></label>
    <select id="yearlypartnersuppliermaintainance" name="yearlypartnersuppliermaintainance" class="searchselect searchselectstyle partnersupplierselect select2-hidden-accessible" tabindex="-1" aria-hidden="true">
    </select><span class="select2 select2-container select2-container--default select2-container--below select2-container--open select2-container--focus" dir="ltr" style="width: 250px;"><span class="selection"><span class="select2-selection select2-selection--single" role="combobox" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="true" tabindex="0" aria-labelledby="select2-yearlypartnersuppliermaintainance-container" aria-owns="select2-yearlypartnersuppliermaintainance-results"><span class="select2-selection__rendered" id="select2-yearlypartnersuppliermaintainance-container"></span><span class="select2-selection__arrow" role="presentation"><b role="presentation"></b></span></span></span><span class="dropdown-wrapper" aria-hidden="true"></span></span>
</div>
```

Comment: Can we see the resultant html produced from this code?

Comment: @Steve Added it, hope it'll help

Comment: might be because once you have called `select2` on the selectbox, the html structure is regenerated and the `click` event is not being triggered for dynamically generated elements. makes sense?

Comment: @Mike that makes sense indeed! Guess that's the only possible reason. Any idea how to solve this? I'm very new to JS

Comment: @Derp actually you need to check the html structure after `select2` has been applied. If the structure is not changed you can bind events for dynamically generated elements as mentioned in @Diego's answer. 

but what happens most of time is that actual selectbox is hidden, and select2 like plugins insert their own `div` structure, so you click only on their divs not on your selectbox, in which case your click event will not get triggered.

Comment: You can either use `select2` api so you bind code to `select2`'s specific events, or whenever the radiobutton is changed, you can destroy `select2`, which gives you your original structure back and then again bind the event as you have done already.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your js to:

```
var choice = 'partner';

$(document).on('click', '.partnersupplierselect', function(){
    var group = $(this).parent().parent();
    choice = group.find('.partnersupplier:radio:checked').val();
    console.log(choice);

    group.find('.partnersupplierselect').select2({
        ajax: {
            dataType: "json",
            type: "POST",
            data: function (params) {
                return {
                    term: params.term,
                    '_token': token,
                    'choice': choice
                };
```

When dynamically generated, the DOM changes are not event linked in jQuery, so you use `$(document).on('event','element',function(){...});` to trigger the event on the element...